# Serve auto-generated zip files with small footprint

Tags: linux, centos, zip, nginx

I currently use mod_zip/nginx(for automatically generating zip files).

The (very very big) issue with mod_zip is - when it accepts range requests - it doesn't pass ranges to subrequests.

What happens is, with download managers that are fairly aggressive, the entire files are loaded from HDD for every request(resulting in 100MB/sec disk IO for 80Mbit of download bandwidth.. that is a crazy waste)

My question is:
What can I use to create zipped archives on the fly with a low memory footprint, that has resume/range-request support, and can load files from URLs while zipping?

The server may have 100 users downloading in parallel - pre-generating is thus not an option.

https://github.com/evanmiller/mod_zip/ - what I currently use

I know of piping zip output, but that command doesn't have URL support nor range-request support(as far as I know)